# Lync 2011 application is not launched instead iMessage is launched in MAC

Tags: macos, lync

I have a MAC and i am trying to start lync 2011 from my web application. Below is the code of my web application(html).

When i click on the link for the voice call (tel) it launches Microsoft Lync but when i click the link for the IM instead of Lync, the iMessages application is launched. I want to launch Lync for IM too.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="text">
Call me at <a href="tel:+11002003004">(100) 200-3004</a>
<br>
IM me at <a href="im:abc@hotmail.com">chat</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Hari

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default messaging application on your machine by doing the following:

- Open 'Messages'
- Select the Application Menu
- Select 'Preferences'
- Select your desired Application the 'General' tab:

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22403?locale=en_US

[image: Setting default messaging app on Mac]

Of course, this only changes this behavior on your local machine.  It will not affect any other visitors of your web app.  The behavior on their machines would be governed by the default app selected on their machine.